# Transcrypt not converting strip() function

Tags: html, arrays, string, transcrypt

So, I have this python file that generates a list of numbers and converts them into a string:

```
def gen():

    array = []
    for value in range(10):
        array.append(value)
    random.seed(20)
    random.shuffle(array)

    array_str = str(array)
    array_str = array_str.strip('[]')
    array_str = array_str + '.'
```

where there is a line in a HTML code in an HTML file elsewhere that runs the `gen()` function stated here.

However, when Transcrypt is run on that Python code, the `array_str.strip('[]')` part of the code doesn't seem to be converting well as the outer square brackets of the generated list `[]` is still seen on the webpage when I run the server. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: well there's something missing from this code, since you define `array` make it with random ints and then you redefine it as `gen_random_int` whatever that is. Is that the 5 lines of code above?

Comment: would be helpful to see also more of the code, e.g. the html/transcrypt code

Comment: might also be this is just not supported by Transcrypt: https://github.com/QQuick/Transcrypt/issues/41

Comment: Oh ya ignore the gen_random_int() thing. That line shouldn't be there. I edited the code in the question.

Comment: For transcrypt, the Python code shown here is in a file called 'library.py', then I ran transcrypt on my terminal using ```python -m transcrypt -b -n library```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simply [not supported](https://github.com/QQuick/Transcrypt/issues/41) to use `.strip` for anything other than whitespace at the moment.

Looking at the generated javascript code you can see Transcrypt runs:

```
var array_str = array_str.strip ('[]');
```

with `.strip` defined as

```
String.prototype.strip = function () {
    return this.trim ();
};
```

You can try just removing the first and last characters as a workaround if the brackets are always at beginning and end (which I suppose they should be), something like this:

```
def gen():
    array = []
    for value in range(10):
        array.append(value)
    random.seed(20)
    random.shuffle(array)

    array_str = str(array)
    array_str = array_str[1:-1]
    array_str = array_str + '.'
```